# Margin: 0 auto и height:100% . Не устанавливается высота

Tags: вёрстка, html5, css, height

Даже если указывать `position:absolute` для блока.

Смотрите вот тут. Слева сайдбар, нужно сделать на 100 проц. высоту. Без джаваскрипт. Футер должен быть прижат к низу как и есть сейчас.

http://personal.96.lt/personal.html

Пока делаю с javascript но думаю что и без него можно сделать.

Comment: Все, теперь норма! Спасибо @HA3IK. У меня просто position:relative на wrap стоял!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из самых основных фактов, что бы сохранить высоту объекта 100% - надо: до этого объекта, всем родительским блокам, присваивать ***height: 100%***;

Вот, возможно то, что вам надо:
**CSS**:

```
*{ margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 100%;}
html, body{ height: 100%; }
.deFloat{ clear: both; }
#wrap{ margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; min-width: 500px; 
       min-height: 450px; height: 100%; font-family: sans-serif;
       background: #eaeaea;}
.sideL{ width: 200px; height: 100%; background: #353535; float: left; }
footer{ width:100%; height: 30px; background: #000; 
        color: #eaeaea; text-align: center;}
.middleBlock{ margin: 0 auto; width: 300px; height: 300px; 
              background: red; border: 2px solid black; }
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrap">
   <div class="sideL"></div>
   <div class="middleBlock">ориентировочный текст</div>
   <p class="deFloat"></p>
   <footer><p>подвал</p></footer>
</div>
```

**Пример:**
http://jsfiddle.net/HA3IK/6bcmP/

Comment: Надо чтобы он был по центру. margin:0 auto

Comment: Так?  
http://jsfiddle.net/HA3IK/6bcmP/1/

Comment: @HA3IK .sideL по центру.

Comment: Вот ) http://jsfiddle.net/HA3IK/6bcmP/2/  
Что бы центрировать абсолютный блок: надо задать отступ left: 50% и отнять margin-left: половина ширины Вашего центрального блока

Comment: Ну это почти оно, только это не как сайд бар,мне надо для внешнего марджин такой чтобы сайдбар был слева. Тогда будет 100 пропцентов как мне нужно. Спасибо!

Comment: Какой у меня будет тогда margin-left в том случае, тут проценты никак не годятся? Мне надо чтобы была определенная ширина. Ширина сайта 960 px. Даже если position:absolute высота 100 проц не ставится

Comment: Так? http://jsfiddle.net/HA3IK/6bcmP/4/ Центральный блок (красный) по центру, а серый возле него слева.

Comment: Лучше не использовать для центрирования отрицательные маргины ,т.к. неизвестно заранее, какой блок ширины. `transform:translate(-50%, -50%)` решит проблему раз и навсегда, каких бы габаритов блок не был, хоть изменяющихся на лету.